# How do I specify the default install path of an msi in cx_freeze and distutils?

Tags: python, distutils, cx-freeze

I am trying to create an installer from a Python application we coded. I wrote a simple setup.py file and it generates a .msi file no problem, but I can't figure out the way to specify the default install path. We don't want it to install to the default "C:\Program Files" directory. Help?

Comment: So I found I can add the "--initial-target-dir" flag to the line:
`python setup.py bdist_msi --initial-target-dir` but I was hoping to do it in the setup.py file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distutils is rather limited in functionality when it comes to creating installers.  I would suggest you use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) instead.  Its quite simple and lets you customise a lot more than distutils.

The other way would be to manually add --initial-target-dir to the argument list in setup.py (before calling the `setup` function):

```
if 'bdist_msi' in sys.argv:
    sys.argv += ['--initial-target-dir', 'c:\default\path']
```

Comment: The caveat to this was that we need it to be compatible with Python 3, which, if I am reading the site correctly, NSIS does not support. Apologies for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: NSIS should work with anything - its not specific to python and doesn't rely on python, so the python version doesn't matter.  There is another way your could do it too though, and I've updated the answer with it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that in the current version, adding the following to your setup script provides the same functionality:

```
setup(
    ...
    options={'bdist_msi': {'initial_target_dir': 'C:\\alternate\\start\\path'}}
    ...
)
```

Note that it requires the backslash, not the forward slash.